# How to execute a Python script in Windows Powershell?

Tags: python

I want to execute a Python script using Powershell.

Script I wrote:

[image: Script I wrote]

Error coming up as:

[image: Error coming up as]

Comment: your python path is not installed in the environment variable.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Then edit your question to include textual code, not screenshots of stuff. Having to re-type your code makes it so much harder for anyone to help you with future probelms.

Comment: I got it man. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Either python is not installed, or python is missing in your path
[Install python on windows](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/windows.html)

Then you need to add it to your path so powershell can see it:

```
C:\>set PATH=C:\Program Files\Python 3.6;%PATH%
C:\>set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib
C:\>python
```